# Pass the first value that changes in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of vectors.
e.g.

```
[1 0 1]
[1 0 1]
[1 0 1]
[2 1 1]
[2 1 1]
[3 4 0]
...
```

Now I want to pass my vectors to a function but every same vector only **once**:

```
[1 0 1]
[2 1 1]
[3 4 0]
...
```

I already calculated the number of different elements in the list like this:

```
clusternumber = [x for n, x in enumerate(X_list) if x not in X_list[:n]]
n = len(clusternumber)
```

Is there maybe a way to combine it?
What is the fastest way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Loop over the original list, with a variable called `previous`, and only add to the result list if `current != previous`.

Comment: Fastest way to achieve would be using sets (but no order) but I assume you already have that answer in `clusternumber`.

Comment: @Austin yes kind of, but clusternumber calculates my strings (sentences) before they are vectorized. Appearently I cant run this code on numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `set`:

```py
data = [[1,0,1],[1,0,1],[1,0,1],[2,1,1],[2,1,1],[3,4,0]]
unique_data = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in data)]
print(unique_data)
```

Output:

```py
[[2, 1, 1], [3, 4, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: Interestingly it computes a different length of results than my function 'clusternumber' 'clusternumber' calculates the different words before vectorization and yours afterwards.
any ideas why?